# Terraform fails remote-exec (aws/ec2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When trying to execute a shell script throw provisioner "remote-exec" in terraform connection not establish

I'm using ami for `ubuntu-xenial-16.04` so the user is ubuntu

This is the last code that I use to execute the shell script:

```
resource "aws_instance" "secondary_zone" {
  count = 1
  instance_type = "${var.ec2_instance_type}"
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.latest-ubuntu.id}"
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.deployer.key_name}"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.secondary.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids =  ["${aws_security_group.server.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["${template_file.script.rendered}"]
  }

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
  }
}
```

This is what get in console:

```
aws_instance.secondary_zone (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_instance.secondary_zone (remote-exec):   Host: x.x.x.x
aws_instance.secondary_zone (remote-exec):   User: ubuntu
aws_instance.secondary_zone (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.secondary_zone (remote-exec):   Private key: true
aws_instance.secondary_zone (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
aws_instance.secondary_zone (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
```

Thank you for your help...

Comment: Does your instance's security group allow SSH access from your machine that is running Terraform?

Comment: yes of course,

I change the provisioner type to "file" and then provisioner "remote-exec"

Comment: This is a bit of an environmental question really so will be difficult for anyone to answer. But as a checklist of things to try: Can you SSH into the instance with that user/key combination from the machine running Terraform when not using the provisioner? Does the connection time out eventually when running the provisioner? Does it error in some way?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR 
I think you are right. when I tried to apply it from another location it connects ok.

In addition **template_file** is deprecated so I change the code.
I share it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. In your connection block try specifying the host.

```
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
    host        = self.public_ip
  }
```

I also had to create a route & gateway and associate them to my vpc.  I'm still learning terraform, but this worked for me.

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "test-env-gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.test-env.id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "route-table-test-env" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.test-env.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.test-env-gw.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet-association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.us-east-2a-public.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route-table-test-env.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to run some scripts to provision whichever ec2 nodes you create with Terraform, I would try setting the `user-data` parameter to reference your script. The user-data script is run automatically when the node initializes.

This will ensure that there are no lifecycle related issues with your deployment (such as EC2 node being created and the host not being available for the remote exec to succeed) and an overall cleaner experience.

An example of this can look like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "secondary_zone" {
  count = 1
  instance_type = "${var.ec2_instance_type}"
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.latest-ubuntu.id}"
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.deployer.key_name}"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.secondary.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids =  ["${aws_security_group.server.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  user_data = "${template_file.script.rendered}"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Further reading:
[TF docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data)
[Userdata examples](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Terraform/Terraform-terraform-userdata.php)

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned, it was connecting problem in my case.

In addition `template_file` was deprecated so I change the code  to:

```
resource "aws_instance" "secondary_zone" {
  instance_type = "${var.ec2_instance_type}"
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.latest-ubuntu.id}"
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.deployer.key_name}"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.secondary.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids =  ["${aws_security_group.server.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

    connection {
    type     = "ssh"
    user = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
    timeout = "2m"

  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "/server/script.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/script.sh"
  }  

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "chmod +x /tmp/script.sh",
      "/tmp/script.sh args",
    ]
  }
}
```

Also, I learned that the scrip.sh have to be formatted as `LR`

Comment: I don't think this answer really solves the question though and your question is basically inherently unanswerable other than "open your security group/other network policies to the instance to allow SSH from the machine running Terraform"

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that's not the case. The solution is here but isn't called out sufficiently for anyone to notice. This works because of the private_key line in the connection stanza.

Comment: this does not work when you leave host out of connection. I dont understand what is working in your solution. Like the last comment said "The solution is here but isnt called out." I cant work out what the solution here is.